# Static Employee number increase, file handling issue

Tags: java, file-handling, static-variables

I am having a problem with my Employee number static variable with file handling. When I create a new Employee I automatically get the next number in sequence, which is saved to a file. But when I recompile the program and create a new Employee the employee number reverts back to 1 instead of reading from the file the last employee number created and continuing from that employee number.

Is there any method that anyone might suggest to read the previous employee and continue numbering from there? I have added my employee & file handler class for reference.

Thank you in advance any any help! :)

```
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Employee extends Person implements Serializable
{   
    private Date dateOfBirth; 
    private Date startDate;
    private double salary;
    private int employeeNumber;
    private static int nextEmployeeNumber = 1;  

    private final double MAX_SALARY = 70000;
    private final double INCREMENT = 250;


    public Employee()
    {
        super();
        dateOfBirth = new Date();
        startDate = new Date();
        salary = 0.0;
        employeeNumber = nextEmployeeNumber++;
    }



    public Employee(String title, String firstName, String surname, String         phoneNumber, 
                int day, int month, int year, int sD, int sM, int sY, double         salary)
    {
        super(title, firstName, surname, phoneNumber);
        this.dateOfBirth = new Date(day, month, year);
        this.startDate = new Date(sD, sM, sY);
        this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber++;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    //Overrides the toString methods, providing its own implementation
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return(super.toString() + "\nEmployee Number: " + employeeNumber +         "\nEmployee Salary: " + salary + 
                          "\nEmployee DOB: " + dateOfBirth + "\nEmployee         Start Date: " + startDate);
    }


    //Both .equals methods are usable. To save any possible conflicts as might occur 
    //in a larger system, I have set the equals method to call back to the Object class
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
    {
        Employee other = (Employee) otherObject;
        if (otherObject == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(getClass() != otherObject.getClass())
        {   
            return false;
        }

        if(super.name.equals(otherObject)&&
          (employeeNumber == other.employeeNumber)&&
          (dateOfBirth == other.dateOfBirth)&&
          (startDate == other.startDate)&&
          (salary == other.salary));
        {
           return true;
        }
    }

    int quit = 0;
    public void read()
    {   
        Scanner kbInt = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner kbString = new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.print("\n\nEmployee Title: "); 
        name.title = kbString.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee First Name: "); 
        name.firstName = kbString.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee Surname: "); 
        name.surname = kbString.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee DOB Day: "); 
        dateOfBirth.day = kbInt.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee DOB Month: "); 
        dateOfBirth.month = kbInt.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee DOB Year: "); 
        dateOfBirth.year = kbInt.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee Phone Number: "); 
        phoneNumber = kbString.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee Start Day: "); 
        startDate.day = kbString.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee Start Month: "); 
        startDate.month = kbString.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee Start Year: "); 
        startDate.year = kbString.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee Salary: "); 
        salary = kbInt.nextDouble();
    }



    //Getters & Setters of DOB, start date, employee number & salary
    public Date getDateOfBirth() 
    {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) 
    {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Date getstartDate() 
    {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) 
    {
     this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;

    }

    public int getEmployeeNumber() 
    {
        return employeeNumber;
    }

    public double getSalary() 
    {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        this.salary = salary;
        if(salary < 0 || salary > 70000)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Enter Valid Salary");
    }

    public void incrementSalary()
    {
        if(salary + INCREMENT <= MAX_SALARY)
            salary += INCREMENT;
        else
            salary = MAX_SALARY;
    }       
 }


       import java.util.*;
       import java.io.*;
       import java.nio.file.*;

       /**
        * Class B.Sc. CSDF
        * Instructor Maria Boyle
        * Description: EmployeeMenu class for Hotel application
        * Date: 01/11/2015
        * @author Mark Melling
        * @version 1.0
        */

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //   This class contains an ArrayList, and the methods for modifying  //
        //   the ArrayList as required, as well as the methods for serializing//
        //   and deserializing the ArrayList                                  //
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

       @SuppressWarnings("serial")
       public class EmployeeFileHandler_1 implements Serializable
       {
        //Declare ArrayList called employees - for storing a list of Employees
        private ArrayList<Employee> employees;
        private Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        public EmployeeFileHandler_1()              // Default Constructor
        {
            employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();  // Construct Employee ArrayList
        }


        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Method Name : add()                              //
        // Return Type : void                               //
        // Parameters : None                                //
        // Purpose: Reads one Employee record from the user //
        //        and adds it to the ArrayList employeeList //
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////  

        public void add()
        {
            Employee employee = new Employee();         // Create a Employee object

            employee.read();                            // Read its details 
            employees.add(employee);                    // Add it to the employeeList
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Method Name : list()                             //
        // Return Type : void                               //
        // Parameters : None                                //
        // Purpose: Loops around the ArrayList employeeList //
        //          and prints to screen employee details   //
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public void list() 
        {
            for(Employee currentEmployee : employees)
            {
                System.out.println(currentEmployee);        
            }       
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Method Name: view()                              //
        // Return Type: void                                //
        // Parameters:  None                                //
        // Purpose:     View Employee record from the       //
        //              ArrayList employeeList              //
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////  

        public void view() 
        {
            //Read the number of the Employee to be viewed
            System.out.println("\nEnter Employee Number:");
            int employeeToView = keyIn.nextInt();

            //Read every Employee object in videos
            for(Employee currentEmployee : employees)
            {
                // If it's number equals the number of the Employee to view
                if(currentEmployee.getEmployeeNumber() == employeeToView)
                {
                    //Display Employee
                    System.out.println(currentEmployee);
                    break;
                }
            }   
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Method Name: delete()                              //
        // Return Type: void                                  //
        // Parameters:  None                                  //
        // Purpose:     Reads Employee record from the        //
        //              ArrayList employeeList & deletes user //
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public void delete()
        {
            //Read the number of the video to be deleted from the user
            System.out.println("Enter Number of Employee To Delete");
            int employeeToDelete = keyIn.nextInt();

            //for every Video object in videos
            for(Employee currentEmployee : employees)
            {
                //if it's number equals the number of the Video to view
                if(currentEmployee.getEmployeeNumber() == employeeToDelete)
                {
                    //display it
                    System.out.println(currentEmployee);

                    //Remove it from videos
                    employees.remove(currentEmployee);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Method Name: delete()                              //
        // Return Type: void                                  //
        // Parameters:  None                                  //
        // Purpose:     Reads Employee record from the        //
        //              ArrayList employeeList & edits user   //
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public void edit()
        {
            //Read the number of the employee to be edited from the user
            System.out.println("Enter number of Employee to edit");
            int employeeToEdit = keyIn.nextInt();

            //for every Employee object in employees
            for(Employee currentEmployee : employees)
            {
                //if it's number equals the number of the employee to view
                if(currentEmployee.getEmployeeNumber() == employeeToEdit)
                {
                    //Display employee
                    System.out.println(currentEmployee);

                    //get it's index
                    int index = employees.indexOf(currentEmployee);

                    //read in a new employee
                    currentEmployee.read();

                    //reset the object in employees
                    employees.set(index, currentEmployee);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Method Name : writeRecordsToFile()                //
        // Return Type : void                                //
        // Parameters : None                                 //
        // Purpose: Writes the ArrayList employees to the    //
        //          file employees.bin before closing it     //
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

        public void writeRecordsToFile()
        {
            if(employees instanceof Serializable)
            try
            {
                // Serialize the ArrayList...
                FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream("employees.bin");

                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);

                os.writeObject(employees);

                os.close();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException fNFE)
            {
                System.out.println("Cannot create file to store employees.");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Input Output Error" + e.getMessage());
            }
        }   

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Method Name: readRecordsToFile()                     //
        // Return Type: void                                    //
        // Parameters:  None                                    //
        // Purpose:     Reads the ArrayList employees from the  //
        //              file employees.bin, uses the Path.get   //
        //              method to test whether the path to the  //
        //              file exists & adds error handling.      //          
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void readRecordsFromFile()
        {
            if(employees instanceof Serializable)
            try
            {
                final String FILENAME = "employees.bin";
                Path p = Paths.get(FILENAME);

                if(Files.exists(p))
                {
                    //Creates Object
                    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(p.toString());
                    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);

                    Object o = is.readObject();             //READ an Object from the file
                    if(o instanceof ArrayList)              //IF Object is an ArrayList
                    employees = (ArrayList<Employee>)o;     //ASSIGN Object to employees
                    is.close(); 
                }
                else    
                {
                    System.out.println("File "+p.getFileName() + "Doesnt exist");
                }       
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException fNFE)
            {
                System.out.println("File not found " + fNFE.getMessage());
            }
            catch(IOException iOE)
            {
                System.out.println("Input output error " + iOE.getMessage());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are not serialized in Java, so `nextEmployeeNumber` will not be written to disk. The next time you run your program, it will be set back to 1. 
You can try looking at `employeeNumber` during deserialization and if it's greater than `nextEmployeeNumber` then update the static value. Alternatively, load all of your employees and then iterate over them and do the same comparison.
This assumes that you always load all the records from disk before creating new employees.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Egor..appreciated! :) I manged to get it sorted by adding a method to the file handler: public void setNextCustomerNo()

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void setNextCustomerNo()
{
    Employee tempEmployee = new Employee();//create a customer object

    if(employees.isEmpty())//if there are no records in customers ArrayList
    {
        tempEmployee.setNextNumber(1);//set Customer.nextNumber to 1
    }
    else//If there are records in customers ArrayList
    {
        //get the size of ArrayList -1 to get last element
        //and store that element in tempCustomer
        tempEmployee = employees.get(employees.size()-1);

        //get tempCustomer's Customer Number and +1 to get next number
        //and pass this number to the Customer class to set nextNumber
        tempEmployee.setNextNumber(tempEmployee.getEmployeeNo()+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use a static method for setting the static variable. There's no need to create a new Employee object. I also wouldn't suggest simply grabbing the last Employee's number in the list and assuming that it's the highest. Any kind of sorting or out-of-order insertions would instantly break it.